# Impossible to combine reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, store

### What is the pb?

When I did a pull origin main, I recovered another branch with a reducer in addition to mine. So, I had a conflict with reducers. I created an index.js in reducers folder in order to combine both of them. In store redux, I call the index.js reducer but states aren't read in redux devtools.

### CODE

STORE

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

import reducer from 'src/reducers/genres';
import regionsMiddleware from '../middlewares/regionsMiddleware';
import genresMiddleware from '../middlewares/genresMiddleware';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const enhancers = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(
    genresMiddleware,
    regionsMiddleware,
  ),
);
const store = createStore(
  // reducer
  reducer,
  // enhancer
  enhancers,
);

export default store;
```

REDUCER(jndex)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import genresReducer from './genres';
import regionsReducer from './regions';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  genres: genresReducer,
  regions: regionsReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

GENRES(reducer)

```
import { SAVE_GENRES } from '../actions/genres';

const initialState = {
  genres: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  console.log(`le reducer a reçu une action ${action.type}`);
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_GENRES:
      /*
      - on crée un nouvel objet : {}
      - on déverse dedans toutes les informations du state actuel : ...state
      - on écrase une valeur qui provenait du state actuel
      */
      return {
        ...state, // list: state.list
        genres: action.genres,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

REGIONS(reducer)

```
// import actions
import { SAVE_REGIONS } from '../actions/regions';

const initialState = {
  regions: [],
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_REGIONS:
      /*
      - on crée un nouvel objet : {}
      - on déverse dedans toutes les informations du state actuel : ...state
      - on écrase une valeur qui provenait du state actuel
      */
      return {
        ...state, // regions: state.regions
        regions: action.regions,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

SRC INDEX.JS

```
// == Import : npm
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// == Import : local
// Components
import App from 'src/components/App';
import store from 'src/store';
// bootstrap's Css
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

// == Render
// 1. Root React element (the one that contains the entire app)
// => Creates Nested Object Structure (Virtual DOM)
const rootReactElement = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />;
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
// 2. The target of the DOM (where the structure is to come to life in the DOM)
const target = document.getElementById('root');
// 3. Trigger React (virtual) rendering =dom > (web page)
ReactDom.render(rootReactElement, target);
```

### Screenshots

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your store, you should import the correct reducer.

You now do

```
import reducer from 'src/reducers/genres';
```

but should probably be (*since you want to use the combined `rootReducer`*)

```
import reducer from 'src/reducers/';
```

---

Additionally, since you use the `combineReducers` utility, it will only pass the relevant state to your specific reducers, so you should not return the full path from them.

```
const initialState = {
  regions: [],
};
// and later on
case SAVE_REGIONS:
  return {
    ...state, // regions: state.regions
    regions: action.regions,
  };
```

should become

```
const initialState = [];
// and later on
case SAVE_REGIONS:
  return action.regions;
```

and

```
const initialState = {
  genres: [],
};
// and later on
case SAVE_GENRES:
  return {
    ...state, // list: state.list
    genres: action.genres,
  };
```

should become

```
const initialState = [];
// and later on
case SAVE_GENRES:
  return action.genres;
```

Comment: I've already tried this but it didn't work .. I put "import reducer from 'src/reducers/'; " and remove the empty  grid

Comment: @LaureCHAPERT could you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)  for example, so i can see it in action ?

Comment: I finally found the pb .. In the folder component I called state.genres but It was state.genres.genres ! However, thanks :)

Comment: @LaureCHAPERT the second paragraph of my answer would solve this issue.